# How to alphabetize all of the parts, chapters, sections, and content of an entire document in ConTeXt?

Tags: sectioning, context, sorting

I have a document that is structured like this:

```
\part{Birds}
    \chapter{North America}
        \section{West Coast}
            \mymacro{Bald Eagle}
            \mymacro{Spotted Owl}
        \section{East Coast}
        \section{Alaska}
    \chapter{South America}
        \section{Peru}
        \section{Brazil}
\part{Bears}
    \chapter{Canada}
```

- The preamble appears in a separate file.
- All of the content is added using a custom macro, `\mymacro`, so each item gets a single line.

How can I alphabetically sort all of the parts, chapters, sections, and macros in the document, at each level? E.g., the above would be sorted like this:

```
\part{Bears}
    \chapter{Canada}
\part{Birds}
    \chapter{North America}
        \section{Alaska}
        \section{East Coast}
        \section{West Coast}
            \mymacro{Bald Eagle}
            \mymacro{Spotted Owl}
    \chapter{South America}
        \section{Brazil}
        \section{Peru}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest and least harmful way I can think of is to intercept the ordinary structure macros and do the sorting part in Lua. If you do the grouping right you won’t notice the difference. I’ve outlined an annotated [proof of concept](https://gist.github.com/2601712) that works for your example. Basically, all you have to do is to specify a list of structure elements that should be sorted as well as your command for typesetting the entries (`\mymacro` as you called it, here I stuck with plain `\entry`). The latter takes one compulsory argument but the code could be easily rewritten to allow optional args as well.

The configuration macro `\setupsortstructure` expects the two parameters *sections* (type comma list) and *entry* (macro):

```
\setupsortstructure[
   sections={part,chapter,section,subsection},
   entrycommand=\entry,
]
```

Of course, the entry command needs to be properly defined. From the example:

```
%%% The macro for entries.
\definehighlight [entryhighlight] [style=italic]
\define[1]\entry{%
  \leavevmode
  \noindentation
  \hbox to2em{\hfill·}\hskip.5em
  \entryhighlight{#1}%
  \blank[line]%
}
```

And you’re done! Insert your content between `\starttext` and `\stoptext`, and you will get something like this:
[image: sorted document structure]

Answer (score 4):

I'm rather certain that it should be possible in context. You could write the entries to a csv-file or build a database in the memory and then sort it with TeX or lua. In LaTeX one could e.g. use datatool: (I'm assuming that there is always at least one `\section` entry to keep the code simple, and I didn't try to protect possible fragile commands in the values. The code should only show the princip):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{datatool,ifthen}
\DTLnewdb{animals}
\renewcommand\part[1]{%
 \def\currenttype{#1}}%


 \newcommand\chapter[1]{%
  \def\currentlocation{#1}}

\renewcommand\section[1]{%
  \DTLnewrow{animals}
  \DTLnewdbentry{animals}{type}{\currenttype}
  \DTLnewdbentry{animals}{location}{\currentlocation}
  \DTLnewdbentry{animals}{sublocation}{#1}
  }


\begin{document}     
\dtlexpandnewvalue
\part{Birds} 
     \chapter{North America}
        \section{West Coast}
        \section{East Coast}
        \section{Alaska}    
   \chapter{South America}
        \section{Peru}
        \section{Brazil}
    \chapter{Germany}
      \section{North}
\part{Bears}
    \chapter{Canada}
         \section{Lake}

Unsorted database:

\DTLdisplaydb{animals}

\bigskip

Sorted entries:

\DTLsort{type,location,sublocation}{animals}%
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\bfseries type &
\bfseries location & \bfseries sublocation 
\DTLforeach{animals}{%
\type=type,\location=location,\sublocation=sublocation}{%
\\
\type&\location &\sublocation}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: IIUC, the content of each section should also move. Does the above code work if each section has arbitrary content.

Comment: @Adity: Village wrote "All of the content is added using a custom macro, `\mymacro`," so all is needed is another level. Longer text parts should better be put in external files so that the main text keeps its clear "database like" structure.

Comment: OK. But I still think that TeX is the wrong language to create a database tree. I added a hint about using Lua tables in my answer.

Comment: @Aditya: There are certainly better tools for large databases. But being able to keep everything "inside" TeX can have some advantage. I have quite often used (small) LaTeX-databases e.g. for serial letters.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, ConTeXt cannot sort your input file.

You might be able to get a working version by using `\startchapter ... \stopchapter` version of section heads, storing each section body in a buffer, and using registers to soft each level.

But, I think that if you want to sort your input, then TeX is the wrong input language. Most XML processing tools (including the XML parser in ConTeXt) have access to the complete XML tree, which makes it easier to sort and move blocks. So, for such data, it is better to use XML as an input language.

If your input file follows a restricted TeX grammar, then you may also parse it using a higher-level programming language and sort things there.

Another option will be to simply input your text as a Lua table:

```
\startluacode
thirddata = thirddata or {}
thirddata.contents = {
   "bears" = { -- Part level
        "Canada" = {}, -- Chapter level  
   },
   "birds" = { -- Part level
        "North America" = { -- Chapter level
           "West Coast" = {
                "Bald Eagle",
                "Spotted Owl",
           },
           "East Coast" = {},
           "Alaska" = {},
         },
        "South America" = { ---
         --- ....
         },
    }
 }
\stopluacode
```

You can then write a [ConTeXt Lua Document](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/cld-mkiv.pdf) to convert this data to a TeX document on the fly and process it.