# Sort subsections alphabetically

Tags: sectioning, sorting

We need to make a paper that describes a list of interfaces. The assignment however says we need to sort the interfaces alphabetically. Because this list is quite long (20+) I am looking for a way to sort the subsections (each subsection describes an interface) alphabetically. Without having to move code myself.

Is there a package that can handle this?

Here is a sample of the code:

```
\newcommand{\interfaceItem}[5]{
   \subsection{#1}\label{interfaceItem:#1}
   \paragraph{Paragraph 1}#2
   \paragraph{Paragraph 2}#3
   \paragraph{Paragraph 3}#4
   \paragraph{Paragraph 4}#5
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to have each subsection in a separate file, and then have a program compile the whole document together before leaving it to TeX?

Comment: This sheds some light on your options: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51967/how-to-alphabetize-all-of-the-parts-chapters-sections-and-content-of-an-entir

Comment: Well the subsection itself is written by a macro. I don't think it's that difficult to write the code to a file instead.

Comment: Can you give an indication how your paper is organised? If the whole text of the subsections has to be moved, this is certainly impossible from within TeX if the subsections are not "contained" in some sort of structure.

Comment: I have added a small description.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an implementation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\interfaceItem}{mmmmm}
 {
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l_commusoft_interfaces_seq {#1}
  \cs_new:cpn { commusoft_interface_#1: } {
    \subsection{#1}\label{interfaceItem:#1}
    \paragraph{Paragraph 1}#2
    \paragraph{Paragraph 2}#3
    \paragraph{Paragraph 3}#4
    \paragraph{Paragraph 4}#5
  }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\printInterfaces}{ }
 {
  \seq_sort:Nn \l_commusoft_interfaces_seq
   {
    \string_compare:nnnTF {##1} {>} {##2} {\sort_return_swapped:} {\sort_return_same:}
   }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_commusoft_interfaces_seq { \use:c { commusoft_interface_##1: } }
 }
\seq_new:N \l_commusoft_interfaces_seq
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \string_compare:nnn #1 #2 #3 {TF}
  {
   \if_int_compare:w \pdftex_strcmp:D {#1}{#3} #2 \c_zero
    \prg_return_true:
   \else:
    \prg_return_false:
   \fi
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\interfaceItem{A}{A1}{A2}{A3}{A4}
\interfaceItem{C}{C1}{C2}{C3}{C4}
\interfaceItem{B}{B1}{B2}{B3}{B4}

\begin{document}

\printInterfaces

\end{document}
```

However, a simpler strategy can be easier:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\interfaceItem}[5]{
   \@namedef{interface@\detokenize{#1}}{%
     \subsection{#1}\label{interfaceItem:#1}
     \paragraph{Paragraph 1}#2
     \paragraph{Paragraph 2}#3
     \paragraph{Paragraph 3}#4
     \paragraph{Paragraph 4}#5
    }
}
\newcommand{\printInterface}[1]{%
  \@nameuse{interface@\detokenize{#1}}%
}
\makeatother
```

You define your interfaces as before, in the preamble,

```
\interfaceItem{A}{A1}{A2}{A3}{A4}
\interfaceItem{C}{C1}{C2}{C3}{C4}
\interfaceItem{B}{B1}{B2}{B3}{B4}
```

and then say

```
\printinterface{A}

\printinterface{B}

\printinterface{C}
```

Sorting a list of short commands is easier than sorting big chunks of code.

Answer (score 7):

TeX is Turing complete language so I am sure the problem can be "easily" solved. However, this is best done (at least on Unix) with the standard Unix tools. Create a directory **interfaces** in which you would create a separate **.tex** file for the description of each interface. Something like

```
z-interface.tex
a-interface.tex
q-interface.tex
b-interface.tex
```

Now do something like

```
ls interfaces > interface-names.txt
```

which will create interface-names.txt file with interfaces sorted in alphabetical order. Using awk you can easily add `\input` TeX command in front of each file name. Like

```
awk '{print "\\input",$1}' interface-names.txt > interface-names.tex
```

Now just put the following line

```
\input interface-names.tex
```

into your main **.tex** file and you will have all sub sections in proper order as long as main **.tex** file and interface **.tex** files are in the same directory.