# How to write macro outcome to file

Tags: write

I have a macro \printauthors that contains a list of authors, for example

`John Doe, Barack Obama,...`

How can I write this content to a file, for example `authors.txt`. The command

```
\immediate\write\myfile{\printauthors}
```

doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong or should I use another way?

Comment: Is `\printauthors` the macro I suggested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `\printauthors` is the macro I suggested in [On sorting a string with multiple entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217547/on-sorting-a-string-with-multiple-entries), then it's easy to add the functionality. With this version,

```
\printauthors
```

will just print the names while

```
\printauthors[filename.ext]
```

will output the same data on the specified file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse,l3sort,pdftexcmds}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% a macro from pdftexcmds that works with all engines
\cs_set_eq:Nc \konewka_strcmp:nn { pdf@strcmp }

\NewDocumentCommand{\addauthor}{ o m m }
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   {
    \konewka_add_author:nnn { #3 } { #2 } { #3 }
   }
   {
    \konewka_add_author:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printauthors}{ o }
 {
  \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
   {
    \konewka_print_authors:
   }
   {
    \konewka_print_authors_to_file:n { #1 }
   }
 }

\seq_new:N \g_konewka_authors_id_seq
\seq_new:N \l__konewka_authors_full_seq
\iow_new:N \g_konewka_write_authors_stream 

\msg_new:nnn { konewka/authors } { author~exists }
 {
  The ~ author ~ #1 ~ already ~ exists; ~ it ~ won't ~ be ~ added ~ again
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \konewka_add_author:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \prop_if_exist:cTF { g_konewka_author_#1_prop }
   {
    \msg_warning:nnn { konewka/authors } { author~exists } { #1 }
   }
   {
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_konewka_authors_id_seq { #1 }
    \prop_new:c { g_konewka_author_#1_prop }
    \prop_gput:cnn { g_konewka_author_#1_prop } { fname } { #2 }
    \prop_gput:cnn { g_konewka_author_#1_prop } { lname } { #3 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \konewka_print_authors:
 {
  \__konewka_sort_authors:
  \seq_use:Nn \l__konewka_authors_full_seq { ,~ }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \konewka_print_authors_to_file:n #1
 {
  \iow_open:Nn \g_konewka_write_authors_stream { #1 }
  \__konewka_sort_authors:
  \iow_now:Nx \g_konewka_write_authors_stream
   {
    \seq_use:Nn \l__konewka_authors_full_seq { ,~ }
   }
  \iow_close:N \g_konewka_write_authors_stream
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__konewka_sort_authors:
 {
  \seq_gsort:Nn \g_konewka_authors_id_seq
   {
    \string_compare:nnnTF {##1} {>} {##2} {\sort_reversed:} {\sort_ordered:}
   }
  \seq_clear:N \l__konewka_authors_full_seq
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_konewka_authors_id_seq
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l__konewka_authors_full_seq
     {
      \prop_item:cn { g_konewka_author_##1_prop } { fname }
      \c_space_tl
      \prop_item:cn { g_konewka_author_##1_prop } { lname }
     }
   }
 }

\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \string_compare:nnn #1 #2 #3 {TF}
  {
   \if_int_compare:w \konewka_strcmp:nn {#1}{#3} #2 \c_zero
    \prg_return_true:
   \else:
    \prg_return_false:
   \fi
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\addauthor{John}{Doe}
\addauthor{Harry}{Potter}
\addauthor[Uthor]{Archibald}{\"Uthor}
\addauthor{John}{Doe}
\addauthor{Bill}{Clinton}
\addauthor{Barack}{Obama}

\printauthors

\printauthors[\jobname.txt]

\end{document}
```

The contents of `\jobname.txt` is

```
Bill Clinton, John Doe, Barack Obama, Harry Potter, Archibald \"Uthor
```

Note that I used `\jobname` just not to clobber any of my files.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `\printauthors` from this: [On sorting a string with multiple entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217547/on-sorting-a-string-with-multiple-entries) then this macro isn't expandable, thus it cannot be used in `\immediate\write`. You have to split the processing to the two steps: preparing and using. The "preparing" step does sorting and this macro is not expandable. The "using" step only expands the result of preparing step.

I can show this concept on my example, but you cannot use this code directly because you are not using plain TeX.

```
\input opmac

\def\sort{\begingroup\setprimarysorting\def\iilist{}\sortA}
\def\sortA#1#2{\ifx\relax#1\sortB\else
  \expandafter\addto\expandafter\iilist\csname,#1\endcsname
  \expandafter\preparesorting\csname,#1\endcsname
  \expandafter\edef\csname,#1\endcsname{{\tmpb}{#2}}%
  \expandafter\sortA\fi
}
\def\sortB{\def\message##1{}\dosorting
  \def\act##1{\ifx##1\relax\else \seconddata##1\sortC \expandafter\act\fi}%
  \gdef\tmpb{}\expandafter\act\iilist\relax
  \endgroup
}
\def\sortC#1&{\global\addto\tmpb{{#1}}}

\def\sortauthors{\def\tmp{}\expandafter\sortauthorsA\authors [] {} {}; }
\def\sortauthorsA [#1] #2 #3; {%
   \ifx^#1^\expandafter\sort\tmp\relax\relax \let\sortedauthors=\tmpb
   \else\addto\tmp{{#1}{#2 #3}}\expandafter\sortauthorsA\fi
}
\def\printauthors{\expandafter\printauthorsB\sortedauthors\relax}
\def\printauthorsB#1{\ifx\relax#1\else #1, \expandafter\printauthorsB\fi}

\newwrite
\def\authors{[Doe] John Doe; [Potter] Harry Potter; [Clinton] Bill Clinton;
             [Uthor] Archibald \"Uthor; [Obama] Barack Obama; }

\sortauthors
\immediate\write\myfile{\printauthors}
\bye
```

Comment: On the other hand, my macros work (with minor modifications just because `xparse` isn't available) both with Plain e-TeX and LaTeX. Only the user level macros need to be redefined with `\cs_new...`.

Comment: @egreg On the other hand, my macros work (with minor modifications) in LaTeX too. But it is somewhat absurd to do `\input opmac` in LaTeX, bacause most functionalities (font selection, colors, hyperlinks, bibliography, indexes, references, multilingual support, ...) are iplemented twice in such case. Of course, better in opmac. This is comparable, why I am not doing somethig like `\input latex.ltx` in plain TeX, but TeX by its principle allows this (with minor modifictions).

Answer (score 1):

If `\printauthors` really is just a simple macro that expands to a string, then this suffices:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newwrite\myfile
\newcommand{\printauthors}{John Doe, Barack Obama}
\begin{document}
\immediate\openout\myfile=authors.txt
\immediate\write\myfile{\printauthors}
\end{document}
```

See [How to write a command to file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24639/how-to-write-a-command-to-file)