# Populate table after displaying it

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, lists

I want to create a table which is populated throughout the document but is displayed at the beginning. Something along the lines of

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\questiontable

\addrow{Question 1}{20}
\addrow{Question 2}{30}
\addrow{Question 3}{40}

\end{document}
```

The output should be equivalent to

```
\begin{tabular}{cc}
Question 1 & 20 \\
Question 2 & 30 \\
Question 3 & 40 \\
\end{tabular}
```

This is similar to how a table of contents is created so I expect multiple compilation passes, but I don't know the internals of how that's done. Apologies if this was asked before. I couldn't find similar questions but it is likely because I don't know what to search for exactly. The closest I came across is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152810/how-can-i-create-two-table-of-contents-for-a-solutions-packet-with-one-of-them), but that solution is specific to producing ToC.

I prefer solutions in plain TeX so I can modify them, but any other solutions are much appreciated.

In particular, I am hoping to modify the provided solutions to allow expansion of arguments

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\questiontable

\newcounter{question}
\newcounter{mark}

\setcounter{mark}{10} \setcounter{question}{1}
\addrow{{Question \thequestion}{\themark}}

\setcounter{mark}{20} \setcounter{question}{2}
\addrow{{Question \thequestion}{\themark}}

\setcounter{mark}{30} \setcounter{question}{3}
\addrow{{Question \thequestion}{\themark}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible solution; note the additional braces around the values which are used here for maximum flexibility, so you can have tables with different formats.

I print the table twice to show how to use the keys.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\questiontable}{}
 {
  \exp_args:NnV \begin{tabular} \g_tohiko_qt_spec_tl
  \toprule
  \tl_if_empty:NF \g_tohiko_qt_header_tl
   {
    \tl_use:N \g_tohiko_qt_header_tl \\ \midrule
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \g_tohiko_qt_rows_seq { \\ } \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\addrow}{m}
 {
  \tohiko_qt_addrow:n { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\questiontablesetup}{m}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { tohiko/qt } { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\tohikoaddrow}{m}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_tohiko_qt_rows_seq { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \g_tohiko_qt_rows_seq
\seq_new:N \l__tohiko_qt_temp_seq

\keys_define:nn { tohiko/qt }
 {
  spec .tl_gset:N = \g_tohiko_qt_spec_tl,
  spec .initial:n = { cc },
  cols .int_gset:N = \g_tohiko_qt_cols_tl,
  cols .initial:n = 2,
  header .tl_gset:N = \g_tohiko_qt_header_tl
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \tohiko_qt_addrow:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__tohiko_qt_temp_seq {} { #1 }
  \iow_shipout:cx { @auxout } { \tohikoaddrow { \seq_use:Nn \l__tohiko_qt_temp_seq { & } } }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\questiontablesetup{header={Question & Points}}

\questiontable

\bigskip

\questiontablesetup{header={\multicolumn{1}{c}{Q} & P},spec={lc}}

\questiontable

\addrow{{Question 1}{20}}
\addrow{{Question 2}{30}}
\addrow{{Question 3}{40}}
\addrow{{Question 121}{40}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How to cope with expanding counter values? Here's a possible way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\questiontable}{}
 {
  \exp_args:NnV \begin{tabular} \g_tohiko_qt_spec_tl
  \toprule
  \tl_if_empty:NF \g_tohiko_qt_header_tl
   {
    \tl_use:N \g_tohiko_qt_header_tl \\ \midrule
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \g_tohiko_qt_rows_seq { \\ } \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\addrow}{m}
 {
  \tohiko_qt_addrow:n { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\questiontablesetup}{m}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { tohiko/qt } { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\tohikoaddrow}{m}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_tohiko_qt_rows_seq { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \g_tohiko_qt_rows_seq
\seq_new:N \l__tohiko_qt_temp_seq
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { Nnx }

\keys_define:nn { tohiko/qt }
 {
  spec .tl_gset:N = \g_tohiko_qt_spec_tl,
  spec .initial:n = { cc },
  header .tl_gset:N = \g_tohiko_qt_header_tl
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \tohiko_qt_addrow:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnx \l__tohiko_qt_temp_seq {} { \text_expand:n { #1 } }
  \iow_shipout:cx { @auxout } { \tohikoaddrow { \seq_use:Nn \l__tohiko_qt_temp_seq { & } } }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\questiontablesetup{header={Question & Points}}

\questiontable

\bigskip

\questiontablesetup{header={\multicolumn{1}{c}{Q} & P},spec={lc}}

\questiontable

\newcounter{question}
\newcounter{mark}

\setcounter{mark}{10} \setcounter{question}{1}
\addrow{{Question \thequestion}{\themark}}

\setcounter{mark}{20} \setcounter{question}{2}
\addrow{{Question \thequestion}{\themark}}

\setcounter{mark}{30} \setcounter{question}{3}
\addrow{{Question \thequestion}{\themark}}

\setcounter{mark}{30} \setcounter{question}{121}
\addrow{{\textbf{Q\'uestion} \thequestion}{\themark}}

\end{document}
```

I added formatting to the last case to show that it is respected. However, the real use case might be treated in a different fashion.

[image]

Comment: That's even better than I originally envisioned. I think I understand your solution although I am quite a beginner with expl3. Is the use of expl3 required for this usecase? If not, what should I look for to find a tex solution?

Comment: @Tohiko It's not difficult to do it without `expl3`, but why giving up with its greater flexibility? With this solution you can have as many columns as you like.

Comment: Yes indeed. However, I need to modify the solution a bit (to allow expansion of rows before being inserted) and I am not experienced with `expl3` enough to do this correctly.

Comment: @Tohiko Can you please make a short example of what you intend to do?

Comment: @greg, sorry. I should have done that from the beginning. I thought I could make the modifications myself but this is proving difficult for me. I added a short example that explains my usecase.

Comment: @Tohiko Added a possible solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133758/discussion-between-tohiko-and-egreg).